# How to use Karate with dependency Injection (Picocontainer)

Tags: cucumber, karate

I have a project where I use cucumber, rest-assured, selenium and Appium, I am trying to move API testing to Karate and unable to use it along with picocontainer dependency in pom.xml.

```
    org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$UnsatisfiableDependenciesException: com.intuit.karate.ScriptEnv has unsatisfied dependency 'interface com.intuit.karate.cucumber.KarateReporter' for constructor 'public com.intuit.karate.ScriptEnv(java.lang.String,java.io.File,java.lang.String,java.lang.ClassLoader,com.intuit.karate.cucumber.KarateReporter)' from org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer@66ac5762:11<|
at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector.getGreediestSatisfiableConstructor(ConstructorInjector.java:191)
  at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector.getGreediestSatisfiableConstructor(ConstructorInjector.java:110)
  at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector.access$100(ConstructorInjector.java:51)
  at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$1.run(ConstructorInjector.java:331)
  at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(AbstractInjector.java:270)
  at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjector.java:364)
  at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.getComponentInstance(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:56)
  at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.getComponentInstance(AbstractBehavior.java:64)
  at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.getComponentInstance(Stored.java:91)
  at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:699)
  at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:647)
  at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:632)
  at org.picocontainer.parameters.BasicComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(BasicComponentParameter.java:118)
  at org.picocontainer.parameters.ComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(ComponentParameter.java:136)
  at org.picocontainer.injectors.SingleMemberInjector.getParameter(SingleMemberInjector.java:78)
  at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$CtorAndAdapters.getParameterArguments(ConstructorInjector.java:309)
  at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$1.run(ConstructorInjector.java:335)
  at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(AbstractInjector.java:270)
  at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjector.java:364)
  at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.getComponentInstance(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:56)
  at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.getComponentInstance(AbstractBehavior.java:64)
  at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.getComponentInstance(Stored.java:91)
  at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:699)
  at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:647)
  at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:678)
  at cucumber.runtime.java.picocontainer.PicoFactory.getInstance(PicoFactory.java:40)
  at cucumber.runtime.java.JavaStepDefinition.execute(JavaStepDefinition.java:38)
  at cucumber.runtime.StepDefinitionMatch.runStep(StepDefinitionMatch.java:37)
  at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runStep(Runtime.java:300)
  at cucumber.runtime.model.StepContainer.runStep(StepContainer.java:44)
  at cucumber.runtime.model.StepContainer.runSteps(StepContainer.java:39)
  at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberScenario.run(CucumberScenario.java:44)
  at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberFeature.run(CucumberFeature.java:165)
  at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.run(Runtime.java:122)
  at cucumber.api.cli.Main.run(Main.java:36)
  at cucumber.api.cli.Main.main(Main.java:18)
```

> How can I add karate setup with dependency injection like
>   picocontainer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cucumber DI is not supported by Karate and it is actually not needed.

Because you can very easily call Java code and re-use if needed: https://github.com/intuit/karate#calling-java

But you are encouraged to do everything in Karate and then JS as far as possible, so that you get the most benefit.

Comment: I can see there are various advantages including reuse of other feature files and I am not looking for usinr cucumber DI for karate based feature files. There are other cucumber feature files what requires picocontainer  which are also in the same project.

I was just hoping to make karate and my other feature file  co-exists in the same workspace.

Comment: @AmitVyas unfortunately this is not supported and unlikely to be ever supported. just separate these concerns or drop all the picocontainer stuff

Comment: Thanks for the help!